# How to construct a parent child relation object from another object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For a given object which shows parent-child relation, I would  like to construct another object like expected output.

```
const PARENT_CHILD = {
  'Newton': ['Plato', 'Aristotle'],
  'Aristotle': ['Einstein'],
  'Plato': ['Tesla', 'Edison'],
  'Edison': ['Hawking']
};
```

The resultant return object should look like the below object,

```
{
  "Newton": {
    "son": "Plato, Aristotle"
  },
  "Plato": {
    "father": "Newton",
    "son": "Tesla, Edison"
  },
  "Aristotle": {
    "father": "Newton",
    "son": "Einstein"
  },
  "Einstein": {
    "father": "Aristotle",
    "son": "Hawking"
  },
  "Tesla": {
    "father": "Plato"
  },
  "Edison": {
    "father": "Plato"
  },
  "Hawking": {
    "father": "Einstein"
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? You should build a tree out of the input, then flatten that tree into your expected output.

Comment: Yes, what have you tried? Research Object.entries(PARENT_CHILD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Object.entries(PARENT_CHILD)` along with `.map()` and `.flat()` to create an array of all the names involved. We then create a Set from these to ensure they are unique.

Once this is complete, we can create our new Object, using `.reduce()`, adding a son property if the entity has 'sons' and then adding a 'father' if they have one too:

```js
const PARENT_CHILD = {
  'Newton': ['Plato', 'Aristotle'],
  'Aristotle': ['Einstein'],
  'Plato': ['Tesla', 'Edison'],
  'Edison': ['Hawking']
};

// Get unique names of all entities...
const uniqueNames = [...new Set(Object.entries(PARENT_CHILD).map(([k,v]) => [k, ...v]).flat())];

const result = uniqueNames.reduce((acc,key) => {
    acc[key] = {};
    if (PARENT_CHILD[key]) {
        acc[key].son = PARENT_CHILD[key].join(", ");
    }
    const res = Object.entries(PARENT_CHILD).find(([k,v]) => v.includes(key));
    if (res?.[0]) {
        acc[key].father = res[0];
    }
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log('Result:', result)
```

Comment: This made my day. Thanks a lot Terry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const PARENT_CHILD = {
  'Newton': ['Plato', 'Aristotle'],
  'Aristotle': ['Einstein'],
  'Plato': ['Tesla', 'Edison'],
  'Edison': ['Hawking']
};


let object={};
Object.entries(PARENT_CHILD).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  object[key]={...object[key],'son':value.toString()};
  
  value.map(ele=>{
  object[ele]={...object[ele],'father':key}
  
  });
});

console.log(object);
```